# One of similar files in Git repo disappeared after copy

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs

Ok, so here's the story. We've got git repository with 20-30k lines of code. My workmate copied (copied, not moved) few files in repo to create another module. Content of these files was just slightly modified. Then he made a commit. Meanwhile I worked with some of the files that he copied (the originals) and commited my work. When I was pulling I realized that I've got conflicts in files that I didn't have, since he just created them (copied them). After resolving the conflicts I checked my local repo and I don't have half of the files I suppose to have. I know git tracks the content of the files, not the file names, but right now it's not very helpful.

```
git log remote_repo --stat --diff-filter=D
```

shows that few files was deleted, and

```
git log remote_repo --stat -C --diff-filter=D
```

shows that fewer files was deleted (but still some)

We need both copies of files so what should we do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to rebase and try resolving the conflicts again. This may be simple or slightly more complex. If it is simple you will only nee to rebase the merge and fix the files that were deleted. Try this:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~1
```

You will be presented with a screen asking what you want to do to each commit.
It will be something like:

```
pick bb009b7 merge commit

# Rebase 9775146..bb009b7 onto 9775146
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
```

Change pick to edit, save and quit the editor. You are now back in the merge commit. Run:

```
git checkout <id of the previous commit> <filename>
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
```

That should fix it. If it doesn't, you'll need to go back further and it may be more complex.

I would guess that it would go something like this:

```
# rebase the last three commits, assuming:
#  the oldest is your most recent changes
#  the next is your co-worker's
#  the last is the merge
# You can probably go back only two but I generally
# go back one extra just to see that things are as I 
# expect.

git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

You will be presented with a screen asking what you want to do to each commit.
It will be something like:

```
pick 8d25cf0 Your changes
pick e9ddd29 His changes
pick bb009b7 merge

# Rebase 9775146..bb009b7 onto 9775146
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
```

Leave the first line as is. Change pick in the second to edit. The last I think you want to edit as well.

Write and save this and the rebase will begin. It will run through the first commit and stop at the second. Your files should be missing. You now want to run:

```
git checkout <id of the previous commit> <filename>
```

And that will restore files deleted by your coworker.

Then run:

```
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
```

When you get to the merge commit just check to make sure that things are as you expect. If files are missing try checking them out again. Then amend and continue. You should now have everything you need.

**If you feel things are going wrong at any point**

```
git rebase --abort
```

This will put you back to where you started and you can try again.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I need to rebase and force push to our remote repo and also tell everyone involved to discard and pull this branch again?

Comment: I suppose you could try doing the `git checkout <id of the previous commit> <filename>` in your current commit as long as having commits in the history without those files is not considered a problem.

Comment: I would rather like to have history of those files so as soon as I will get back to work I will try rebase first.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful. After long day my head was empty, because it was the first time when I saw that kind of situation, but now I learned how to deal with this. I used rebase, but I did something like this: rebase, then edit wrong commit of my coworker, then reset HEAD^ to reset this commit and do it all over again but with caution and after that I droped branch from remote and push my new branch. After that I need to inform everyone (2 other teammates) and cherry-pick from reflog some commits on their local repositories